# React Input Mask date format

Tags: regex, reactjs, input-mask

so I'm using this package [react-input-mask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-input-mask) to mask my input fields, for a specific field I'm using it to mask a date that I would like to appear as YYYY-MM-DD until filled, however, the package only allows me to mask with a single mask character, therefore I just chose X until I come up with a solution but haven't been able to, here's the code for one my fields running this.

```
<InputMask
                    mask="9999-99-99"
                    maskChar="X"
                    value={values.issue_date}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                  >
                    {() => (
                      <LNTextField
                        name="issue_date"
                        label="Issue Date"
                        error={
                          touched.issue_date && errors.issue_date ? true : false
                        }
                        helperText={
                          touched.issue_date && errors.issue_date
                            ? "* " + errors.issue_date
                            : ""
                        }
                        type="text"
                        className={classNames(
                          styles.inputField,
                          styles.override
                        )}
                      />
                    )}
                  </InputMask>
```

Comment: This doesn't look possible for this component. You most probably have to use another or derive your own.

Comment: Any suggestions for others?

Comment: Use 3 separate fields then. It will require a bit more coding to work smoothly but you will be able to use dedicated placeholder chars then.

Comment: What would 3 separate fields achieve? what exactly are you suggesting?